# Failed to build build_runner:build_runner:Try using an explicit extension application of the wanted extension or hiding unwanted extensions from scope

Tags: flutter, freezed

I can not use `flutter pub run build_runner watch --delete-confilicting-output` to generate freezed file. the error is:

Failed to build build_runner:build_runner:
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/analyzer-0.41.2/lib/src/error/best_practices_verifier.dart:258:50: Error: The property 'displayString' is defined in multiple extensions for 'TargetKind' and neither is more specific.
-- 'TargetKind' is from 'package:meta/meta_meta.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/meta-1.7.0/lib/meta_meta.dart').
Try using an explicit extension application of the wanted extension or hiding unwanted extensions from scope.
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/analyzer-0.41.2/lib/src/error/best_practices_verifier.dart:1950:14: Context: This is one of the extension members.
String get displayString {
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/meta-1.7.0/lib/meta_meta.dart:91:14: Context: This is one of the extension members.
String get displayString {
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/analyzer-0.41.2/lib/src/error/best_practices_verifier.dart:260:36: Error: The getter 'commaSeparatedWithOr' isn't defined for the class 'List'.
-- 'List' is from 'dart:core'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'commaSeparatedWithOr'.
var validKinds = kindNames.commaSeparatedWithOr;

**yaml file is:**

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.14.3 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.1.1
  location: ^4.3.0
  firebase_core: ^1.10.0
  cloud_firestore: ^3.1.0
  flutter_bloc: ^8.0.0
  bloc: ^8.0.0
  freezed: ^0.12.7
  dartz: ^0.10.0
  freezed_annotation: ^1.0.0
  
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0
  build_runner:
  analyzer: 
  # ^1.12.2
  freezed: 
  #^1.12.0
```

Comment: Were you able to find any solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

For all those who are  experiencing this problem, just overwrite the "meta" dependency.

just add these lines to pubspec.yaml

```
dependency_overrides:
meta: 1.6.0
```

This might solve your issue, and there is well discussed github discussion
https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/46687